# Add a specific condition to "Latest" module using vQmod

Tags: module, opencart, opencart-3, vqmod

Using **vQmod**, I'm trying to add a condition to select only products which will be available at the current date (in order only these ones are displayed with the "Latest" native module).

I have tested with something like:

```
<search position="replace">
    <![CDATA[           'sort'  => 'p.date_added',
    ]]>
</search>
<add>
    <![CDATA[
     # Before the current date
     'sort'  => 'p.date_available <= NOW()',]]>
</add>
```

But it seems not to have any effect...

Comment: 'sort' is for sorting not for selecting.

Comment: You're right of course, I had to be overworked. :-\
So, the problem is to find how to modify the selection clause for this module.

Comment: @P.Mergey You need to make changes in model function. Selection clause is not possible in controller.

Comment: Latest module uses `getProducts` function, `getProducts` function uses `getProduct` and `getProduct` already has `p.date_available <= NOW()`, you don't need to add it again.

Comment: @DigitCart : Thank you for taking the time to explain the nesting of these functions.